# how to insert an upside-down triangle?

Tags: symbols

I tried inserting an upside-down triangle with `\triangledown` but even when I put the two `$` signs around it, I keep receiving an error.
Does anyone know how to insert such special characters?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `\triangledown` requires the `amssymb` package, so let’s begin by eliminating the obvious: are you loading that package?  Ah, and [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/69818)  I didn’t notice it before.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If the error message is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \triangledown

l.3 $\triangledown
                  $
?
```

then a package is missing, which provides the symbol. For example, package `amssymb` provides the symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\triangledown$
\end{document}
```

> [image: \triangledown of amssymb]

If you want to have the [nabla symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol), then this symbol is available without additional packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\nabla$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I was actually looking for the nabla symbol but didn't know they are different. Thank you so much!